# Converting a string to List<int> for a bluetooth UUID

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter plugin flutter reactive ble for bluetooth, and to do certain things it takes a Uuid object, which takes a List, but my UUID's are in Strings so I am not sure how to convert.

What I have tried:
A text to decimal converter online, this was for testing, but it did not work, but ideally I need to find a way to programmatically do this in Dart.
https://cryptii.com/pipes/text-decimal

```
ble.scanForDevices(withServices: [Uuid([48, 48, 48, 48,.......<etc>])], scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency).listen((device) {
      //code for handling results
      if (!deviceListTechnical.contains(device.id)) {
              deviceListTechnical.add(device.id);
              print(device);
              try {
                BuildList(device);
              } catch(e) {
                print(e);
              }
            }
    }, onError: (error) {
      //code for handling error
      print(error);
    });
```

Comment: There are many ways to encode a string--a sequence of characters--as a sequence of integers.  Do you want to encode the string as ASCII?  UTF-8?  UTF-16?  UTF-32?  Something else?

Comment: Did you try `Uuid.parse`? https://pub.dev/documentation/uuid/latest/uuid/Uuid/parse.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution thanks to @Richard Heap is Uuid.parse

```
var parsed_uuid = Uuid.parse("...");

    ble.scanForDevices(withServices: [parsed_uuid], scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency).listen((device) {
      //code for handling results
      if (!deviceListTechnical.contains(device.id)) {
              deviceListTechnical.add(device.id);
              print(device);
              try {
                BuildList(device);
              } catch(e) {
                print(e);
              }
            }
    }, onError: (error) {
      //code for handling error
      print(error);
    });
```